# Determine possible values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ of $\triangle ABC$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Consider $\triangle ABC$ with sides $a$, $b$, and $c$ units. Also, consider $\triangle XYZ$ that is similar, but not congruent to $\triangle ABC$.

Determine the possible values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ satisfying the following criteria:

- $a, b, $and $c$ are natural numbers.
- $a \le b \le c$
- Two sides of $\triangle ABC$ are congruent to two sides of $\triangle XYZ.$

I've tried to use Pythagorean Triples, but none of them seem to work.

I'm not even sure how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x$, $y$, $z$ be the sides of triangle $XYZ$, with:
$$
a:b:c=x:y:z.
$$

As two sides of $XYZ$ are the same as two sides of $ABC$, we have two possibilities: either $x=b$ and $y=c$ or $y=a$ and $z=b$, all the other cases being impossible or leading to congruent triangles. In the first case we get:
$$
a:b:c=b:c:z,
$$
that is:
$$
a:b=b:c=c:z.
$$
That means that numbers $a,b,c,z$ form a geometric progression: there exists some number $k>1$ such that:
$$
b=ka,\quad c=k^2a,\quad z=k^3a.
$$

Triangular inequality $c<a+b$ leads to $k^2<k+1$, that is:
$$
k<{1+\sqrt5\over2}.
$$
That suggest a way to get all the solutions: if $m$ and $n$ are two coprime positive integers satisfying
$$
1<{m\over n}<{1+\sqrt5\over2},
$$
then a primitive solution is given by
$$
a=n^2,\quad b=x= mn,\quad c=y=m^2,\quad z={m^3\over n}.
$$
Obviously, any multiple of numbers $a,b,c,z$ gives another (non-primitive) solution.
Note that the second case leads to the same result for $a, b, c$, but with $x={n^3\over m}$, $y=n^2$ and $z=mn$.

The smaller primitive solution is obtained for $n=2$ and $m=3$:
$$
a=4,\quad b=6,\quad c=9.
$$